# r - join only consecutive markers with lines in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

I'm trying to overlay a barplot with a scatter plot in plotly. I've managed to plot both and everything looks nice using only markers, but I need to join the markers. Using `lines+markers` it joins every point with each other, like a closed path. I suppose the problem is that my x-axis variable is categorical and I don't know how to fix it. I can't write the original code but is something like:

```
to_plot2[, cat_var := as.factor(cat_var)]

pp2 = plot_ly(to_plot2) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~cat_var, y = ~var_1, type = 'bar', name = 'bar',
            marker = list(color = '#C9EFF9'),
            hoverinfo = "text") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~cat_var, y = ~var_2, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', name = 'lines', yaxis = 'y2',
            hoverinfo = "text") %>%

  layout(title = 'foo',
         xaxis = list(title = "", type = "category",
                      categoryorder = "'array'"),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y", showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE))
```

and the output is:

[image: --]

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the problem. Setting `cat_var` as key it reorders the dataframe in the appropiate manner.

Thanks!